# Shuffle List of strings, but not too much

Tags: c#, list, shuffle

I have a list of strings in C# such as:

```
List<string> myList;
```

Lets say I populate it by adding 20 strings, starting from "1", up to "20".

```
myList.Add("1"); // And so on...
```

How can I, in the most efficient and elegant way, randomly shuffle this list of strings while restricting how far each item of the list can end up from it's original index to, say, 4 .

Example of what I want:

I want the order:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

For example, to be shuffled to the following:

> 2 5 4 3 6 1 8 7 10 9 12 11 15 14 13 16 18 15 20 19

One (straightforward) way of doing it would be to split the list into four parts and shuffle the parts separately. But I am still not sure how efficient this would be.

Efficiency in my case means not doing something that is overcomplicated or just stupid.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's the purpose?

Comment: Your straightforward way is more restrictive than your specification. Your specification allows for your example starting with 2 5 4 3 6 ... but your straightforward way cannot produce it. So what is it that you want?

Comment: You might want to ask this on http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KrisVandermotten when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat. Sure. I should have said "You might want to ask this on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com _instead of here_", as I think that, strictly speaking, this question is off topic for stack overflow

Comment: Algorithm questions are on-topic at both sites.

Comment: I think we can see it as a C# question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `Linq` will create a new index where the new index is limited to `distance` places away from original index

```
List<string> list = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
Random rng = new Random();
int distance = 4;

List<string> newList = list
    .Select((s, i) => 
        new {OrigIndex = i, NewIndex = i + rng.Next(-distance, distance+1), Val = s})
    .OrderBy(a => a.NewIndex).ThenBy(a=>a.OrigIndex)
    .Select(a => a.Val)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you alot. That worked exactly as I described that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
List<int> myList = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToList(); // Feed the list from 1 to 20

int numberByGroups = 4;
List<int> result = new List<int>();

for (int skip = 0; skip < myList.Count; skip = skip + numberByGroups)
{
    result.AddRange(myList.Skip(skip) // skip the already used numbers
                          .Take(numberByGroups) // create a group
                          .OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()) // "Shuffle"
                          .ToList());
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", result));
```

Which will shuffle by groups of `numberByGroups`